# Making Boolean field with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, attribute-table, fields-attributes, boolean

With QGIS is very simple create a Boolean field, I need do the same with ArcGIS Pro.

[image]

After a lot years I use this ESRI product, last one there was ArcGIS 9.x. I remember that with the old ArcGIS version was simple create a Boolean field.

Comment: Neither shapefile nor file geodatabase support Boolean type. Esri doesn't support those types in RDBMS/NoSQL that support them, either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to ArcGIS Pro documentation they don't support Boolean type in feature classes and tables, see https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geodatabases/overview/arcgis-field-data-types.htm

Suggest to create Short Integer field and work with `0` and `1`.

Comment: I disagree on this choice from ESRI. The most important and popular DBs have a boolean field, Oracle, Postgres, MySQL and others. It's incredible that a Geodatabase can't use directly this kind of field.